# save pandas data frame to nested dict by splitting keys and reducing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, recursion

Trying to convert a pandas DataFrame to a dictionary. Pandas utility `to_dict` with `orient` options doesn't seem to be sufficient for this case. My current code works in some cases.

Questions: 
1. Any suggestions to modify current code to make it look elegant and possibly faster?
2. How to add recursion in this scenario to make it work for arbitrary level of nesting.

```
fs = {'b1':{'f:ban':6, 'f:app':4}, 'b2':{'f:ban':4, 'f:app':2}}
dF = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(fs, orient='index')
pandas.DataFrame.to_dict(dF, orient='index')
>>>{'b1': {'f:app': 4, 'f:ban': 6}, 'b2': {'f:app': 2, 'f:ban': 4}}
```

I want this to store like this, splitting the keys and grouping/reducing the values:

```
{'b1': {'f': {'app': 4, 'ban': 6}}, 'b2': {'f': {'app': 2, 'ban': 4}}
```

My code is working for this level of nesting however, there could be a concise way to do this.

Original dictionary:

```
fruits = {'b1': {'f:app': 4, 'f:ban': 6}, 'b2': {'f:app': 2, 'f:ban': 4}}
```

First define a helper function to create a nested dictionary from a flat list:

```
def create_nested_dict(L):
    if len(L) == 2:
        return {L[0]:L[1]}
    while len(L) > 2:
        d = {}
        key = L[0]
        L = L[1:]
        d.update({key:create_nested_dict(L)})
        return d

L = ['f', 'app','4']
create_nested_dict(L)
>>> {'f': {'app': '4'}}
```

Then use the above function

```
new_fruits = {}
for key in fruits.keys():
    _d = {key:{}}
    for k,v in fruits[key].items():
        L = k.split(':')
        N = create_nested_dict(L + [v])
        if list(N)[0] in list(_d[key]):
            _d[key][list(N)[0]].update(N[list(N)[0]])
        else:
            _d[key].update(N)
new_fruits.update(_d)

print (new_fruits)
>>> {'b1': {'f': {'app': 4, 'ban': 6}}, 'b2': {'f': {'app': 2, 'ban': 4}}}
```

My code fails for the following cases. Notice an extra level of nesting

```
fruits = {'b1': {'f:app:sim': 4, 'f:app:del': 3, 'f:ban:del': 6}, 'b2': {'f:app:sim': 2, 'f:app:del': 5, 'f:ban:del': 4}}
>>> {'b1': {'f': {'app': {'sim': 4}, 'ban': {'del': 6}}}, 'b2': {'f': {'app': {'sim': 2}, 'ban': {'del': 4}}}}
```

One key:value pair is missing
    ...{'app': {'del': 3},..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive approach to your problem:

**First**, transform the keys of the nested dictionary to be usable for the recursive nesting function. To accomplish this, `tuplize` simply creates a new dictionary with keys being tuples instead of strings with `:` delimiters:

```
fruits = {'b1': {'f:app:sim': 4, 'f:app:del': 3, 'f:ban:del': 6}, 
          'b2': {'f:app:sim': 2, 'f:app:del': 5, 'f:ban:del': 4}}

def tuplize(to_tuplize):
    return {tuple(keys.split(":")): value 
            for keys, value in to_tuplize.items()}

tupled = tuplize(fruits["b1"])
print(tupled)

>>> {('f', 'ban', 'del'): 6, ('f', 'app', 'sim'): 4, ('f', 'app', 'del'): 3}
```

**Second**, process each item of `tupled` in a recursive fashion as shown in the `nest_dict` function. How it works is very simple:

- If only one key is left within your tupled key chain, set a value.
- Else, pass the rest of the tupled key chain to the recursive function under the current key and handle possibility of an existing key.

That's it.

```
def nest_dict(to_nest, nested=None):
    if nested is None:
        nested = {}

    for keys, value in to_nest.items():
        first_key = keys[0]
        if len(keys)== 1:
            nested[first_key] = value
            continue

        if first_key in nested:
            nest_dict({keys[1:]: value}, nested[first_key])
        else:
            nested[first_key] = nest_dict({keys[1:]: value})

    return nested

print(nest_dict(tupled))
>>> {'f': {'app': {'del': 3, 'sim': 4}, 'ban': {'del': 6}}}
```

Finally, you can use both helper functions in conjunction within a dictionary comprehension to get your required format:

```
result = {key: nest_dict(tuplize(value))
          for key, value in fruits.items()}
print(result)

>>> {'b1': {'f': {'app': {'del': 3, 'sim': 4}, 'ban': {'del': 6}}},
     'b2': {'f': {'app': {'del': 5, 'sim': 2}, 'ban': {'del': 4}}}}
```